# how to create a column of ascending numbers by a certain value?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

How do I make a list or column in pandas which number in this column increase itself by step of 1 and when it hits an certain number (let's say 5) it return to 1 and repeat this process?
My scripts like below and it won't work as expected:

```
i = 0
lista = []
for i in range(50):
        i += 1
        if i == 5:
            continue
        lista.append(i)

print(i)
# what I wanted from this code is like :
1
2
3
4
5
.
.
.
# repeat printing 1-5 for 10 times
```

Comment: While vectorized solutions are preferable (see answer below), you can achieve the same task with the following code which fixes your one: `for i in range(50): lista.append((i % 5) + 1)`

Comment: What is reason for use loops here?

Comment: My comment was just to let him know how to fix his starting code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the simplest way that occurs to me:

```
lista = []
for i in range(50):
    lista.append(i%5+1)
print(lista)
```

This could also be written as a list comprehension, which is only one line of code and way cooler ;)

```
lista = [ i%5+1 for i in range(50) ]
```

Answer (score 2):

First using loops in pandas is [antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758), mainly if exist vectorized solutions, here [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': np.tile(np.arange(1, 6), 10)})
print (df.head(12))
    col
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     5
5     1
6     2
7     3
8     4
9     5
10    1
11    2
```